# Need help with my initial attempt at a headphone jack switcher

Tags: circuit-design

I'm attempting a little project where I can have three 3.5mm jack inputs, then a switch to direct to a single 3.5mm headphone output.

[Based on a simmilar Instructables page](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Construct-a-35mm-Switch-diy/) but attempting to adapt it for three inputs rather than two.
Here's the highly detailed diagram from that page:
[image]

Coming across this diagram for a three position switch, I thought I had a plan:
[image: DP3T Slide switch]

So I've attached all the components and given it a test
[image]

But it has become apparent that it works a little more like this:

[image]

I'm now coming across diagrams like this one in the bottom right, talking about external jumpers between the pins?
[image]

Am I just using the wrong kind of switch, or do I need to re-jig my wiring and add some jumpers in?

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Logic dictates that having 3 sources feed 1 output means using a 3 position (poles) rotary switch with 2 or 3 sections. DP is only 2 poles, thus only 2 possible sources. The number of poles and number of logical sections/circuits are NOT the same. Please re-think your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got the right switch terminal diagram but the wrong switch!

Here's a photograph of the correct switch. Note the pin spacing.

[image]

[image]

You would need to wire the L & R terminals of the output socket to A0 & B0 terminals of the switch.

Like wise with the L & R terminals of the input sockets to A1 & B1, A2 & B2 and A3 & B3 terminals of the switch.

The common  terminals of the four sockets are to be interconnected.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) So I am needing a switch like this: https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/OS203012MU5QP1/CKN9554-ND/1981425/?itemSeq=330095691 ? And when you say the common terminals are to be inter connected, do you mean that the four wires should just all be connected separate from the switch? Thanks

Comment: Anytime, Adam. Yes, that's the right switch and the common connection would be separate from the switch.

Comment: Thank you, Adam.